# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS resume/boot directly after suspend

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I have a server running Ubuntu Server 20.04. To enable power management, I would like to suspend the system and wake it up as soon as I need it (WoL). The problem I face is that the system does not stay in suspend mode. It directly (some seconds to minutes) after the suspend it boot again.

I have unplugged the server from the network and it seems to stay in suspend mode. As soon as I plug in the network cable, the server startup. So, it might be related to the network interface. I have tested to turn off WoL but it does not help.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It seems to be an issue w/ the Fritz!Box 7490 (v7.21). If I disconnect the router from the local network, the suspend and WoL works fine. The WoL option in the Fritz!Box setting is disabled.

This is the tcpdump on the server w/ repaiting packages from the router (about every 30 seconds):

```
tobias@home:~$ sudo tcpdump -vvveni any ether proto 0x0842
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
10:53:12.443846   B c0:25:06:f4:19:77 ethertype Unknown (0x0842), length 118:
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ..........Ea....
        0x0010:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0020:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0030:  b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ....Ea....Ea....
        0x0040:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0050:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0060:  b42e 99cd 4561                           ....Ea
10:53:12.543643   B c0:25:06:f4:19:77 ethertype Unknown (0x0842), length 118:
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ..........Ea....
        0x0010:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0020:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0030:  b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ....Ea....Ea....
        0x0040:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0050:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0060:  b42e 99cd 4561                           ....Ea
10:53:42.423757   B c0:25:06:f4:19:77 ethertype Unknown (0x0842), length 118:
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ..........Ea....
        0x0010:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0020:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0030:  b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ....Ea....Ea....
        0x0040:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0050:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0060:  b42e 99cd 4561                           ....Ea
10:53:42.523736   B c0:25:06:f4:19:77 ethertype Unknown (0x0842), length 118:
        0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ..........Ea....
        0x0010:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0020:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0030:  b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd  ....Ea....Ea....
        0x0040:  4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e  Ea....Ea....Ea..
        0x0050:  99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561 b42e 99cd 4561  ..Ea....Ea....Ea
        0x0060:  b42e 99cd 4561                           ....Ea
```

**UDPATE**

I've restarted the Fritz!Box and the problem seem to be fixed. I get no repeating packages from the router. The server goes to suspend mode if idle and start w/ WoL. The problem now is that the server does not awake if I request the computer. Ports in the router are set and the option to use WoL if a request from the internet arrives is enabled. But this problem seems to be a Fritz!Box related issue.

Comment: Does the server have a mouse or any wireless devices, such as a Bluetooth keyboard, attached to it? If so, these will sometimes send data to the system and trigger a wake up.

Comment: No external devices are attached to the server. I found out that by disconnecting my router (Fritz Box 7490) from my network, the suspend and WoL works like a charm. It seems to be an issue w/ the Fritz Box router. WoL option is disabled in the backend of the Fritz Box.